# C# Generating a random IP Address

Tags: c#, random, ip

I have been working on some mocking for IOT devices and I need to generate a random IP address in C#. What is the most simple way to create a random IP address is C#?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use an `IPAddress` object:

```
var data = new byte[4];
new Random().NextBytes(data);
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(data);
```

Note: If you are doing this several times, you should create just one `Random` object and reuse it.

If you want to ensure that the first element is not zero, you should OR it with 1 before passing it to the IPAddress constructor:

```
data[0] |= 1;
...
```

If you want an IPV6 address, replace the first line with:

```
var data = new byte[16];
```

and you'll get an IPV6 address.

Comment: this could also produce `0.x.x.x` which is invalid

Comment: @fubo It's not invalid as far as the `IPAddress` class is concerned; it will happily create such an address, but I guess you should account for it if it is significant for the unit test.

Comment: @fubo Aye, easiest way is to OR it with 1 (thereby still keeping the randomised top 7 bits).

Answer (score 6):

Based on using visual studio 2017 and string interpolation

```
    public string GetRandomIpAddress()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return $"{random.Next(1, 255)}.{random.Next(0, 255)}.{random.Next(0, 255)}.{random.Next(0, 255)}";
    }
```

Comment: better to say c# 6.0 or greater (or .net framework 4.6). You can use string interpolation with visual studio 2015, not neccessary 2017